# How to convert microseconds to date and time in laravel?

Tags: laravel, flutter, date, datetime, time

I have a project, the project is using flutter and laravel. The date and time that saved in flutter is in microseconds using flutter function "microsecondsinceepoch()". Now I want to convert it in laravel so it becomes date and time. Help me to convert it, because I've already looked at the internet but the internet just shows me how to convert it from miliseconds not mircoseconds. Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$mil = 1357133639816;
$seconds = $mil / 1000;
$new date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($seconds));
```